# What exactly happens when an object is instantiated in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I know that when creating an object of a class the constructor builds that object. Say I had these two class:

```
class Vehicle {
    public int a = func();

    public int func() { 
        System.out.println("9"); 
        return 9;
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c = new Car();
    }
}
```

The output of this project is "9". But why does that happen? What exactly happens when the Car constructor is called? I know that there is some type of default constructor but I am not sure how it exactly works.

Can anyone explain me the object construction with the above example?

Comment: Learn to refer to the Java Language Specification to find out such stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler provides a [default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) for `Car` which is effectively:

```
Car() {
    super();
}
```

And likewise `Vehicle` as a default constructor of:

```
Vehicle() {
    super();
}
```

Fields are initialized as part of initialization, *after* the call to the superclass constructor. So it's *as if* the `Vehicle` class was actually written like this:

```
class Vehicle {
    public int a;

    Vehicle() {
        super();
        a = func();
    }

    public int func() { 
        System.out.println("9"); 
        return 9;
    }
}
```

Now does that makes sense?

See [section 15.9.4 of the Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4) for a much more detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

When the `Car constructor` is called a default call to it's super constroctor is made by the compiler which then intializes all the `Super class's instance fields`. during the initialization of your `a field` as it invokes `func()` method which has a sysout thus it prints 9.

```
public Car() {
super();// this invokes parent class's default cons
}

public Vehical() {
super();// invokes Object constructor then initializes all the instance variables of class vehical
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The JVM is informed that a `Car` must be constructed.
2. The JVM determines that it is a `Vehicle` and therefore triggers a `Vehicle` construction.
3. The JVM understands that the construction of a `Vehicle` requires the initialisation of the `int a` instance variable.
4. The `int a` variable must be initialised to be the result of the call to `func` so `func` is called.
5. `func` has been called so the code prints **"9"**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of `Car c = new Car();`.

That statement creates an object reference, and that object's reference is `c`. The statement `new Car();` creates an object and the reference of that object is sent stored in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

When an object is created it initiates all instance variables present in that object.(to its variable's default value if no assignment is given).

If a default constructor of a particular class(**Car**) is called, a call to the default constructor of its super class(**Vehicle**) is made first. And while creating Vehicle object its instant variable "a" is assigned to function func() and it ll be executed, Hence printing 9.